# sidenav overflows in mobile devices

Tags: javascript, css

The mobile navigation is pushed out of view so that when the user clicks the hamburger icon it slides in. The issue I am facing is that the website on mobile devices is overflowing vertically showing the navigation. I want to prevent that. I have added the HTML in code section.

here is my code

```html
    <header class="header">
    <article class="logo-container">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo-link"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" class="img-logo"></a>
    </article>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <div class="hamburger-container" aria-controls="primary-navigation" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="bar" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            </div>
            <ul class="unorderd-list">
                <li class="list-items"><a href="index.html" class="nav-links">Home</a></li>
                <li class="list-items"><a href="#about" class="nav-links">About</a></li>
                <li class="list-items"><a href="#service" class="nav-links">Services</a></li>
                <li class="list-items"><a href="#price" class="nav-links">Price</a></li>
                <li class="list-items"><a href="#contact" class="nav-links">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
     </header>
```

CSS

```css
    .header {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .header .navbar {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .header .navbar .unorderd-list {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 6.25rem;
        right: -18.125rem;
        width: 18.125rem;
        height: 12.5rem;
        background-color: #111;
        z-index: 1000;
        transition: all ease-in 300ms;
    }
```

Js

```
    function mobileNav() {
        const hamburgerContainer = document.querySelector('.hamburger-container');
        let openNav = false;
        hamburgerContainer.addEventListener('click', () => {
            if(!openNav) {
                openNav = true;
                hamburgerContainer.classList.add('active'); 
               document.querySelector('.unorderd-list').style.right = 0;
            }else {
                openNav = false;
                hamburgerContainer.classList.remove('active');  
                document.querySelector('.unorderd-list').style.right = '-18.125rem';
            }
        });
    }
    mobileNav();
```

I tried overflow, and overflow-x hidden on the header element, the nav element, and the unordered list, but nothing worked. I used the visibility property to hide the navigation but still the website overflows. I was hoping that it would fix the problem but it did not.

Comment: Put html also. And also adjust the code in question, so we can run and see the issue. Thanks

Comment: add the overflow hidden for body instead header. try this body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

Comment: Muneeb Shoukat means the function described here: https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/